# Microphone not working in Ubuntu 14.04.01

Tags: microphone

My laptop is Lenovo B40 and it has Ubuntu version 14.04.01.

The microphone is not working on Skype and Google hangouts.
It is not a hardware issue as it works on windows.
I have checked the sound settings, and the input section, 
the microphone is not on mute.
Please help, have no idea how to fix this!!

Comment: Did you try this? Solution:
1) Download Pulse Audio Volume Control from Ubuntu Software Center.
2) Run it.
3) Select Tab "Input Devices"
4) In Port the default selection is "Internal Microhpone". Change this to "Microphone (unplugged)"
5) Now the mic should work. https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Linux-Discussion/Lenovo-B5400-Microphone-doesn-t-work-in-Ubuntu-14-04/td-p/1574204

Comment: And please see if this can help you http://www.zyxware.com/articles/4857/solved-microphone-not-working-in-skype-in-ubuntu-on-a-lenovo-b40

Answer (score 0):

You have one of two problems, assuming that Ubuntu came with the device driver for your Mic:

1. go to the top right corner of your screen
2. right click on the speaker icon
3. go to sound settings
4. then click on the input tab in the window that opens up from the previous step
5. look for the Mic you are trying to troubleshoot on the left side of the screen, if it is not present, you have a driver problem or if its a USB device, the USB is bad or its simply not plugged in all the way. If it is there, click on it and in the right box turn the input volume all the way to 100%
6. talk into the Mic, if the bar moves with orange color, to Ubuntu, the Mic is working if it doesn't move its an problem with your physical Mic: Ubuntu recognizes the device but the physical device is broke.

#### Note: allot of special integrated devices (built in Mic) and Ubuntu don't get along (I know mine doesn't), some special edition laptops (not sure if a lenovo b40 qualifies) with their special devices don't have released drivers to third parties, during production, manufactures integrate their driver into windows or whatever the laptop comes with.

If you still have the manual the laptop came with, reference that and see if there is a download site somewhere for the driver if its missing.

Comment: It's also possible that both USB port and device work correctly, the driver appears in the list of sound inputs and outputs, while the micrphone/headphones still do not work.  I've tested this using multiple headsets (Kotion Each G2200, Logitech H390, Sennheiser PC 8 USB) in all possible USB ports on the Ubuntu machine.  All the tested headsets work on other non-Ubuntu machines and all Ubuntu machine USB ports work with other USB devices.  The sounds input/output simply shows up in the list when plugged in but does not work.